# How Does The Linux Disk Cache Work With iSCSI and GFS2?

Tags: linux, gfs, disk-cache, gfs2

I'm planning to share a GFS2 filesystem via iSCSI to my web servers.

Are the files read by my web servers cached locally using the linux disk cache stored in memory or are they only cached on the GFS2 cluster?

Answer (score 1):

If they are opened read-only on each node, they are cached locally.  It depends on how the files are lock

Comment: You can read [this](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Global_File_System_2/s1-ov-lockbounce.html) to understand better what JRyan tried to summarize on this answer.